# How can I get a Filename from a string using Regex

Tags: python, regex

I have this string here:

```
"['\r\n                    File: FLO_JIUWASOKLDM_05_HetR_IUSJA_&_Cracks.mp4', <br/>, '\r\n                    Size: 48.14 MB                ']"
```

and I have this regex `\w+\.\w+`

And I want the regex to get the filename `FLO_JIUWASOKLDM_05_HetR_IUSJA_&_Cracks.mp4`

But it breaks at the ampersand, which returns `_Cracks.mp4` what do I need to do to fix it? I'm super new to Regex.

Comment: hey man , so all you need is the text with *.mp4 until the previous space ?

Comment: the file ends with different types .zip, .rar, .mp4, etc

Comment: You need `re.search(r"File:\s*([^']+)", s).group(1)`

Answer (score 1):

There are many options to exercise here, one for example, would be:

```
([^\s]+\.[a-z][a-z0-9]+)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8qZytj/1/)

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"([^\s]+\.[a-z][a-z0-9]+)"

test_str = "\"['\\r\\n                    File: FLO_JIUWASOKLDM_05_HetR_IUSJA_&_Cracks.mp4', <br/>, '\\r\\n                    Size: 48.14 MB                ']\"
"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

Answer (score 1):

`\w` is the shorthand for "word character", meaning letters, numbers, and underscore. Note the lack of ampersand. To include the ampersand, you could use the character class `[\w&]`. Your regex would then be

```
[\w&]+\.\w+
```

- BTW note that this may also match `48.14` depending on the regex function you use.

But maybe you want to include more characters than just ampersand. How about all non-whitespace characters?

```
\S+\.\w+
```

- This uses `\S`, which is the inversion of the whitespace shorthand `\s`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of figuring out what characters the file name may contain (note it may even contain spaces usually), you mayleverage the context: you know it starts after `File:` and space(s) and runs up to the `'`.

So, you may achieve what you need using

```
m = re.search(r"File:\s*([^']+)", s)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

See the [online Python demo](https://rextester.com/DGMD51320).

See also the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tEJqWE/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=File%3A%5Cs*(%5B%5E'%5D%2B)):

[image]

**Details**

- `File:` - a literal substring
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `([^']+)` - Capturing group 1 (`match_object.group(1)`): 1 or more chars other than `'`.